# block decode failed (-22) error solo mining while submitting block

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration

Hi I have developed hardware/software to mine bitcoin it's working and getting me the results (getting nonce since the design takes only .2sec to complete the task)i am trying to submit in my local bitcoin wallet its  error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./submit_b.py", line 282, in <module>
    rpc_submitblock(rpc_con(),block_miner(rpc_getblocktemplate(rpc_con()),binascii.b2a_hex('Bitmatriz'.encode()).decode(), "19DvxDw7zfiBDcvZCyhboNjJ2VW6d2mD2P"))
  File "./submit_b.py", line 124, in rpc_submitblock
    message = rpc_con.submitblock(param)
  File "/home/bitmatriz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 141, in __call__
    raise JSONRPCException(response['error'])
bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -22: Block decode failed
```

Below is the data generated from the script

```
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
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the output as text, instead of a screenshot image?  It will be much easier for people to look at.  If you indent it four spaces, it will show up as "code".

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that the output of your script has an odd number of characters which means it is not valid hex. I'm guessing that you forgot a 0 when you copy and pasted it. So adding a 0 to the front of the data, there's still several things wrong with it.

If this is meant to be a Bitcoin block, then you are missing one of these fields in the block header: time, bits, or nonce (I can't tell which because all three are 4 bytes).

Then after that, you have serialized incorrectly the compact size unsigned integer for  the number of transactions. Firstly, it looks like you are missing a byte for it; you have `0xfd` which indicates that the number should be two bytes. However the number you have put is only 1 byte. Secondly, that integer is in the wrong order. The serialization itself should have `0xfd` first, and then the number that follows in little endian.

Next in your coinbase transaction, it looks like you have missed the segwit marker byte.

These are the things I see wrong with the beginning of your block; something else may be wrong further in the block.

---

Of course I could be completely wrong if the format of your block is not the same as Bitcoin's.

Comment: Thank you! I built the complete structure using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vsergeev/ntgbtminer/master/ntgbtminer.py Let me know if anything is wrong in this